# Can you force VB6 to re-save every file in the project?

Tags: vb6

Let's say you update your project to a new OCX reference. As a result the GUID and other details of that OCX will change in the project's VBP file. So far so good.

However VB6 also writes the same information to FRM files (and maybe others, like user controls). But these files are NOT updated until they themselves are specifically / manually saved. This can lead to confusion when it appears that references are inconsistent.

There are other sorts of automatic changes VB6 makes to files also, but seemingly only when you touch the file manually.

It would be very handy if there were a way to force VB6 to resave every file and make sure it is totally up to date - say, on the build machine. Then you'd know for certain what the most up to date clean copy was as a point of comparison.

I don't know of a command-line option that can do this... but maybe someone knows a trick.

Comment: Usually VB will not let you remove a reference that is in use. It will display a message saying "Can't remove control or reference; in use".

Comment: For .vbp to be updated with new versions of referenced projects when building on the build server we just check `Auto Increment` in `Version Number` frame in project properties. This forces IDE to save the .vbp when it's compiled from command line.

Answer (score 1):

There's an add-on created by Martin Liss in this thread:
[SaveAll.DLL](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28534439/VB6-Is-there-a-Shortcut-for-Save-Entire-Project.html)

I didn't try it myself but it could do what you are looking for. I assume you tried Save Project?

Comment: I'll try that out, thank you. Save Project seems to save only what has been changed manually.

Comment: Martin's comments indicate that the addin "calls sendkeys to send Alt+F followed by v" which will save the project but not explicitly save each and every file in the project. So unfortunately it doesn't quite meet the need despite being somewhat useful anyway.